# OpenSSl error using composer behind proxy on ubuntu

Tags: proxy, composer-php

when i tried to run composer install on ubuntu 18.04 i got this:

```
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL  
operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:                       
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number             
Failed to enable crypto                                                      
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I got the rigth proxy configuration on my /etc/apt/apt.conf and /etc/profile, but the error goes on and on, no mather what i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy configuration needed for using composer is located in /etc/enviroment file.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

http_proxy="http://username:password@10.4.1.20:3128"
https_proxy="http://username:password@10.4.1.20:3128"
```